# set justification of the position of partial and \rho in an equation

Tags: equations

When I use the below command:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    \frac{\partial\rho_{\raisebox{-3pt}{\tiny K}}}{\partial t}
\end{eqnarray}
```

I think the shape is not so good justified particularly, the position of `\partial` and `\rho` are mismatched:

[image]

How can I change the position of `\partial` and `\rho` to get a formula such as:

[image]

in which `\partial` and `\rho` are in a one level of position!!!

Comment: I disagree with your premise... the baseline (not the tops) of the `\partial` and of the `\rho` loop are aligned, which is how those glyphs were [properly] designed.

Comment: Think on `\rho` as a `p` with depth.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing you can do. It is just the were it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, letters such as `p`, `\rho`, and `y` (in mathmode or plain) will always look odd when compared to non-descender characters. In the case where you really really want to align all characters, there are two ways to do so:

The first one is redefining `\rho` so that it would be vertically shifted `3pt`:

[image: Option 1 output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Copied from TeX.SE but I didn't save where I got it explicitly :(
\let\plainRho\rho
\renewcommand{\rho}[1][0pt]{%
  \mathrel{\raisebox{3pt}{$\plainRho$}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \noindent Using the plain \verb|\plainRho| vs the modified version  \verb|\rho|:
    \begin{align*}
        \frac{{\partial{\plainRho}_{{K}}}}{\partial t} & ~ &
        \frac{{\partial{\rho}_{{K}}}}{\partial t}\\
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The second option is to make shift the input all together rather than going through individual letter. Note the subscript using `\down` and `\furtherDown`.

[image: Option 2 output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\up[1]{\mbox{\raisebox{2.5pt}{\ensuremath{#1}}}}                 % Raise the input.
\newcommand\down[1]{\mbox{\raisebox{2.5pt}{{\tiny\ensuremath{#1}}}}}        % shift input down but within reason.
\newcommand\furtherDown[1]{\mbox{\raisebox{-1pt}{{\tiny\ensuremath{#1}}}}}  % shift subscript further


\begin{document}
    \noindent Using original vs \verb|\up{\rho}|
    \begin{align*}
        \text{Original: }\frac{\partial\rho_{\down{K}}}{\partial t} &
        \text{~~~Using $\backslash$up\{$\backslash$rho\}:~~~}\frac{\partial\up{\rho}_{\down{K}}}{\partial t}
    \end{align*}

     \noindent Using \verb|\up and \down| vs \verb|\up and \futherDown|
     \begin{align*}
        \frac{\partial\up{\rho}_{\down{K}}}{\partial t} &
        \frac{\partial\up{\rho}_{\furtherDown{K}}}{\partial t}\\
    \end{align*}

    \noindent Shifting $y$ instead of $\rho$:
    \begin{align*}
        \frac{\partial y_{\down{K}}}{\partial t} &
        \frac{\partial\up{y}_{\down{K}}}{\partial t}\\
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, `\rho` is a character with a descender much like `p`, so it should not be raised relative to the `\partial` which sits on the baseline.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\( \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\rho \quad abgdp \quad \partial \)

\end{document}
```